# $x/sin(x)$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show $\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)}$ is not bounded in the left neighborhood of $\pi$. So if I say their exists M such that $\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)}<M$ I get a contradiction if $M< \pi$ but what do I do when $M$ is greater than $\pi$?

Comment: The problem is that $\sin(x) \to 0+$ as $x \to \pi-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x\to\pi$, 
$${x\over \sin(x)} \sim {x\over \pi - x}.$$
Now analyze what happens as $x\downarrow\pi$ and $x\uparrow\pi$.

Comment: The equivalence is due to the fact that $sin(x)=sin( \pi - x)$ and $\pi - x$ is close to zero?

Comment: Or you can think about the tangent line there.  Both analyses work quite nicely.

Comment: $\sin'(\pi) = -1$ and $\sin(\pi) = 0$.